# SQL query to return single value matching exact values in another column of same table

Tags: sql, mysql

```
Table:  Dummy

|Colum1 | Colum2 |
|:------|:-------|
| 219   | 217    | 
| 219   | 218    | 
| 228   | 218    |
| 228   | 225    |
| 229   | 218    |
| 229   | 220    |
```

I need result set where if user provided numbers in where clause should exactly match along with its count example. if user sends where ( 217,218 ) then it should return with colum1 has value 219.

Following queries is returning the result set as below.

```
SELECT *
from Dummy
GROUP BY Colum1 
having count(distinct Colum2 ) = 2 and Colum2 in (217, 218);
```

```
| 219   | 217    |
| 228   | 218    | 
| 229   | 218    |
```

required output:

```
| 219   | 217    |
```

The no of distinct Colum2 is dynamic , it can be 2 ,3 ,4 or 5.

Comment: First you say want (217, 218), then you need (219, 217) - why did you change your mind?

Comment: `and c2 in (217, 218)` – you allow both values there, so why do you expect not receiving one of them?

Comment: Questionable SQL anyway, at very least it's not portable (e.g. postgreSQL wouldn't accept for at least one requested column (`column2`) neither being within `group by` clause nor being aggregated)...

Comment: Do you just want to discard surplus results? Which value would then have priority? You could order by column2 (ascending or descending depending on needs) and then just restrict the result to one single row (`LIMIT 1`).

Comment: @Aconcagua , I want 219 only..  whatever comes with that no issue. updated questions.

Comment: `Colum2 in (217, 218)` should be in `WHERE` clause, not your `HAVING` clause.

Comment: @user1191247 , share me the complete, query, where in clause wont return exact combination of match, it will return all.

Comment: I'm not fully sure what you *actually* want to receive – you just give a single example and a query that doesn't provide the desired result – could you give a general description what the query actually *should* do? It seems at least that you want to get groups that have exactly two different values (like 7 combined with 10, 12, 12, 10 – and yes, acknowledged, this number can vary...). Then what about the other two numbers? With `in (...)` you might get groups where at least one value is within that range – do you want to have all of matching?

Comment: Maybe: *'I need result set as single row who has values ( 217, 218 )'* -> *'I need those distinct values of column1 where for column2 exist all values of (217, 218) and no other ones'?*

Comment: Just noticing: You added `217` back to the result set – Then question arises: If you indeed want to include a value from column2, *which* one? You only can have one, thus you need to *aggregate* – this could be e.g. the minimum, i.e. `SELECT d1.colum1, MIN(d1.column2) FROM ...`

Comment: @Aconcagua , yes because my query is select * so thats why i added 217. it doesnt matter to me.

Comment: Just that `SELECT *` is not valid in given case – and generally should be avoided anyway. Select those columns you are really interested in, this reduces transmission overhead and is robust against database changes if columns are added, especially inserted in between, or moved – or at least provokes failure if the change is incompatible, instead of resulting in unexpected behaviour which might be difficult to track down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @[user1191247](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191247/user1191247)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76070967/1312382) and assuming you want to get those groups where the list of values of column2 comprises *exactly* the values `{217, 218}` (none less, none more) *then* the following query can give you the desired result:

```
SELECT d1.colum1
FROM dummy d1 JOIN dummy d2 ON d1.colum1 = d2.colum1
WHERE d1.colum2 in (217, 218)
GROUP BY d1.colum1 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT d1.colum2) = 2 AND COUNT(DISTINCT d2.colum2) = 2;
```

The basic idea of is: The self-join assures we have column2 duplicated, then we can filter out all unwanted values within one of the duplicated columns, but leave them in the other. If all wanted values exist the count of the *filtered* column needs to equal the number of these values – and the count of the *unfiltered* column needs to alike, otherwise surplus values would exist (note that the latter's count then would be greater; it cannot ever get smaller, though).

See user1191247's modified [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/G3_O1tUb) (only the query for two values is adjusted).

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `Colum2` criterion to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT Colum1
FROM Dummy
WHERE Colum2 IN (217, 218)
GROUP BY Colum1 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Colum2) = 2;
```

As pointed out by Aconcagua, you could add a `NOT EXISTS` if you want to include only the `Colum1` values which do not have any other `Colum2` values:

```
SELECT Colum1
FROM Dummy d
WHERE Colum2 IN (217, 218)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Dummy WHERE Colum2 NOT IN (217, 218) AND Colum1 = d.Colum1)
GROUP BY Colum1 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Colum2) = 2;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qlyRXW09)

Comment: Wait a second – assume we have yet another row `(219, 219)` in the original table – that one would be excluded by the `where` clause, then again `219` would be included in the result, but if I interpret the question right it shouldn't any more! I'd rather assume we'd need something like `where not exists select 1 from ... where id not in (217, 218)` somewhere...

Comment: Who knows? As you pointed out, the question is not well worded.

Comment: That's the problem, indeed. Played with your [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/maTcyrUO) a bit. I'd assume 300 should not be included then in first grouping query, but we actually need clarification by the question author...

Comment: @Aconcagua, I have rephrased the questions, please revisit once.

Comment: @Aconcagua
https://dbfiddle.uk/ZreScuYN , Please check 2nd box, its getting 219 and 228 , i need 219 only

Comment: @SarangRN Remains unclear, though. You still do not answer if surplus values are to be ignored, as long as both 217 *and* 218 do exist (then this answer is fine) or if you are only interested (what I suspect...) in those groups where no such surplus values exist (then mine is)...

Comment: There's a minor error in your fiddle, though – you didn't adjust the count from 4 to 3 for selecting 3 values only, see https://dbfiddle.uk/bRDu7tJ3...

Comment: @Aconcagua , yes my bad, previous fiddle was having dublicate entries which wont be having in my case, i have updated now. https://dbfiddle.uk/ZreScuYN

Comment: @SarangRN Well, I referred to the fiddle in the answer... Now fixed the link myself ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks! More importantly, I forgot to correlate the `NOT EXISTS` subquery!

Comment: Oh, didn't notice either... My `join` solution enforced this implicitly ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below query:

```
SELECT Parent_Id
FROM Parent_Child
GROUP BY Parent_Id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Child_Id order by Child_Id asc ) = '217,218';
```

Comment: This approach works but is non-sargable.

Answer (score 0):

You could just join the table back on its self

```
SELECT d1.* 
FROM Dummy d1 
JOIN dummy d2
    ON d2.Column1 = d1.Column1
    AND d2.Column2 = 218
WHERE d1.Colum2 = 217
```

Comment: The Column2  values count can be increased to 2 ,3,4...

Comment: Matches the phrase *'I need result set as single row who has values ( 217, 218 )'* at least. Later on the question is contradicting that one, though. My impression is that it simply is completely mis-worded...

Comment: @Aconcagua , i removed that 217 value since it was confusing you. why you are emphasizing on 217 ,  just i need the row who has value 219 as 219 is only having exact match.

Comment: @Aconcagua 

I need https://dbfiddle.uk/ZreScuYN 219 only here you can see its returning two rows in 2nd box.

Comment: @SarangRN There's nothing *'confusing'* me, I'm well aware that you intended something different. But this query matches *exactly* what you phrased *before*, a *'single row'* (indeed...) containing two values, namely *'(217, 218)'*...